# How to get a new access token in exchange of refresh token (when the old access token expires) in Youtube Data API?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am writing a python script to upload videos on youtube using the [sample script](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) provided by youtube itself. But I am having this one problem. When my access token is expired, what should I do with the refresh token in order to exchange it for access token (remember I am writing a python script) or how should I exchange refresh token for an access token?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Refreshing an access token](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Refreshing_a_Token), your application can send a POST request to Google's authorization server that specifies your client ID, your client secret, and the refresh token for the user. The request should also set the `grant_type` parameter value to `refresh_token`.

You may want to check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766073/how-to-update-access-token-using-refresh-token-in-you-tube-api) or this [thread](https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Forum/Use-refresh-token-with-desktop-Python-script/td-p/31863) to know how to implement it using Python.